# Broadcast data from .NET application to another

Tags: .net, networking

I have two applications on a local network A and B, The application A should be the server
and broadcast an array of data to all instances of application B, if the any instance of application B received an item of this array another B instances will not receive this item,
also any instance if application B is able to start before or after application A starting (communication between two applications will not effect).
What is the best technology or method in .NET to apply this scenario?.

Answer (score 1):

The single-delivery means this isn't really a broadcast: you can't "broadcast" and limit it to one receiver. The need to work an A means that it can't be TCP sockets.

It sounds like you want a middleware box in the middle as a work queue. A can add items to the queue, and instances of B can dequeue items. I would use something like redis, because it is trivial to setup, free, and very efficient. In the context of redis, A would call `RPUSH` (to put new items at the end), and each B would call `LPOP` (to remove items from the start). Each B could simply poll periodically when there *isn't* data; when it has removed data it can just `LPOP` in a loop until the data runs out, then poll periodically instead. There is also a blocking pop (`BLPOP`) if you don't want to loop tightly, but I'm not a fan of that personally; if I need to know immediately of new data, I'd rather use the inbuilt pub/sub (`PUBLISH` / `SUBSCRIBE`) to send a "there's new data" message that just makes the clients look with `LPOP`.

There are various redis clients avaiable to .NET.

Other than the individual commands mentioned, most of the above would translate to *any* form of message bus; MSMQ, etc.